# Decidability/Undecidability Question

Tags: automata, turing-machines

Could someone please help me with this question? I'm really having a hard time understanding reductions and decidability.

Prove that the language $$L = \{\langle M,N \rangle \mid M,N\text{ are Turing machines and }L(M) \subseteq L(N)\}$$ is undecidable.

How do I prove this question?

Comment: Depends what you have proved already. Typically, one shows this kind of undecidability by reducing the problem to the halting problem, or one of ts relatives. Have you proved that the problem of finding out whether a language is empty is undecidable?

Comment: Yes I believe I've solved the problem for a turing machine called Lempty and whether it is undecidable or not. How do I link this problem with a problem I've solved before?

Comment: Then you are finished. For if there was a general program for determining whether $L(M)\subseteq L(N)$, then by feeding into it an arbitrary Turing machine $M$ **and** a simple program that accepts only the empty language (easy to make such a TM $N$), you would have an algorithm for determining whether the language accepted by a TM is empty. For $L(M)\subseteq L(N)$ if and only if $L(M)$ is empty.

Comment: @AndréNicolas:  Might as well write that as an answer?

Comment: I would like to notice that it is not commonly accepted to ask basic homework questions on this website. In my opinion, this is considered academic plagiarism. I happen to be in the same class in Calgary as the dear user @Thresh. This is the second instance of you asking the exact specification of an assignment question.
To be at least a little constructive, I will suggest that you can use the fact that Turing machine equivalence is also undecidable, as was covered in class. You can reduce to that by using the basic fact that set equality means that both sets have to be subsets of each other.

Comment: @Manbroski: You might look on meta to see the discussions of how to handle homework.  For example http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4943/homework-policy and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/415/homework-questions-avoiding-giving-a-complete-solution but many users do give complete solutions.

Comment: @RossMillikan: I have no problem with collaboration with others. However, this question (and a number of others for the same class and the same user) are copied verbatim. The comments also indicate that the student has committed minimum time for solving the problem. While there is no way to deal with this, I simply want to bring this to his attention.

Answer (score 2):

The details of the argument depend on what you have proved already. Ultimately, most of the negative results are proved by showing that if there were a Turing machine that could do a certain task, then the TM could be modified to solve the Halting Problem.

From your comment, you have already shown that there is no TM that will recognize when a language is empty.  In that case, you can answer the current question quickly.

If there was a TM for determining in general whether $L(M)\subseteq L(N)$, then by feeding into it an arbitrary Turing machine $M$ and a simple concrete TM $N_0$ that accepts only the empty language, you would have a TM for determining whether the language accepted by a TM  $M$ is empty. For if $N_0$ is our fixed concrete TM for the empty language, then  $L(M)\subseteq L(N_0)$ if and only if $L(M)$ is empty.